# About 50 kcryptd processes in my Android phone?

Tags: linux, android-5.1.1-lollipop

When I use "ps" to check my android phone, I noticed that there are about 50 kcryptd processes occasionally. Normally there is only one.

I googled, but there isn't too much information about process kcryptd.

Has anyone noticed this? Do you know why?

EDIT: I copied a big file to the same folder on my phone for many times, and at the same time I checked the number of kcryptd processes, it was one.*

Comment: You've got encryption on for your device. These are separate work queues for writing (probably). The reason why you notice it is probably due to a lack of hardware assisted encryption on the device. I'm only making semi-educated guesses as to why you're seeing so many of them; but it fits the profile.

Comment: Thank you,  @Petesh. I was also thinking about load of writing. I used a script to copy a big file for 50 times continuously in the same folder on phone, at the same time I checked the processes. Still there is only one. So it is not because of that. I will add this information into my post.

Comment: can you get a snapshot of the process listing at the time you see multiple copies running; just to be sure that it's not something *masquerading* as `kcryptd`

Comment: if there's a bunch of `loopNN` threads at the same time it indicates read/writes to encrypted loop devices, which can be made one `kcryptd` per loop device.

Comment: Yes, @Petesh there are 53 loop threads.  ' 23317 2 3 d538aa00 IN 0.0 0 0 [loop53]'

Comment: at a guess; they're mounted, encrypted `.obb` files; but I have no empirical evidence for that. You may have better luck using `cat /proc/mounts` and checking for locations that may be software package specific which may hint at who's using it. From this point on, though, it's all detective work to determine who's using the files.

Comment: @Petesh, a small update, there are about 30 flush-254:yy processes. It looks like that the loop devices are created by them. I am checking why flush process create loop device, and if the loop device should be deleted when the flush process is killed.

Answer (score 1):

These kcryptd processes (also loopxx processes) are because of moving applications to SD card. Each application on SD card corresponds to one encryptd asec file. They are mounted at /mnt/asec.
See [asec file type](http://www.file-extensions.org/asec-file-extension).